# asdf command not found when run a script remotely with ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, asdf-vm

Following script is on machine A, can run it locally without problem,

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
asdf --version
```

But if we run the script remotely from machine B with following command, it can't find asdf command,

```
$ssh user@A "./test.sh"
./test.sh: line 3: asdf: command not found
```

My command to download asdf,

```
git clone https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git ~/.asdf --branch v0.10.0
```

My ~/.bashrc,

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh
. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash
```

The $PATH printed by script,

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

BTW, if i change the script to something like this,

```
#!/bin/bash -i
asdf --version
```

It can then be run successfully but with some odd output,

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
v0.10.0-77fd510
```

However i am trying to avoid the need for bash -i parameter, so any suggestion?

Comment: Make sure `asdf` is installed on machine B.

Comment: ./test.sh script is on macnine A, not machine B, and we are running it on machine A through ssh from machine B, so i don't think we need asdf installed on machine B.

Comment: It's probably because the path variable is loaded through `.bashrc`, which will do nothing if not run interactively.

Comment: So i source .bashrc in the script, still doesn't work.

Comment: Then it's probably set in some other shell initialization file, like ~/.bash_profile. You will have to look at the setup on machine A to see where the `asdf` program actually is, and how that directory normally gets added to your `PATH`.

Comment: I followed the asdf official document to install it on ubuntu machines, all the settings was added to ~/.bashrc.

Comment: And it means we have these two lines ". $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh", ". $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash" in ~/.bashrc.

Comment: Where (what directory) is the asdf command installed? What is the PATH environment variable set to when you try to run it? Please [edit] your question to include the contents of this .bashrc file, or at least the relevant parts.

Comment: I have added more details for my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute path to the script instead of the relative path.

```bash
$ ssh user@A "/home/somewhere/for/example/test.sh"
```

If you have trouble finding bash, you can also change the hashbang for the script to `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, for example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
asdf --version
```

Use `which` to find the absolute path to `asdf` and use this path in the script. Example finding which bash to use:

```bash
$ which bash
/usr/bin/bash
```

Comment: Absolute path doesn't work to me.

Comment: The point is that if we use #!/bin/bash -i, then the asdf command can be found.

Comment: Try `which asdf` to find the absolute path to asdf.

Comment: On machine A, ```which asdf``` returns /home/user/.asdf/bin/asdf

Comment: source ~/.bashrc in the script doesn't work, but source $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh & $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash directly in the script works.

Comment: Maybe .bashrc exit somewhere when execute in a non-interactive & on-login shell, so the latest two lines of .bashrc doesn't get executed.